# mysql GROUP_CONCAT label results from one column with value from another

Tags: mysql

I have a table that lists urls to product photos.  In the table the photos are listed multiple times (once for the various resizes that have been done during the upload).  The table has three columns of interest:

```
photoFlag photoName objectID
```

Using GROUP_CONCAT i can get all the photo urls for each product but then i lose the photoFlag tag.  the results come as

```
other_columns photoName1,photoName2,photoName3,etc
```

I would like them to come like:

```
other_columns photoFlag1*photoName1,photoFlag2*photoName2,photoFlag3*photoName3,etc
```

So that when processing the result set I can easily pick the best photo options from the list.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT other_columns, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('*', photoFlag, photoName))
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY SomeColumn;
```